# composer autoload psr-4 not working

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm using psr-4 to autoload and create a namespace. But I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Models\User' not found in /app/routes/users.php on line 7
```

My architecture

```
app
---routes
------users.php
---VDB
------Models
---------User.php
```

[image]

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "VDB\\": "app/VDB"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "^0.1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.23",
        "illuminate/database": "~5.0"
    }
}
```

My User.php

```
<?php

namespace VDB\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

}
```

My Route

```
<?php

use \Models\User;

$app->get('/users/:username', function($username) use ($app) {

    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    var_dump($user);

})->name('users');
```

I already tried composer dump-autoload but it didn't work. 
Anybody else who can think about something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your import:

```
use VDB\Models\User;
```

If the class still can't be found, try running

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload.

Comment: When changing that line in the 'my route' file I just get this error:
Fatal error: Class 'VDB\Models\User' not found

Comment: Have you tried regenerating Composer's auto load files?

Comment: Where is `composer.json` located?

Comment: I added a picture to show the location. I already tried the composer dump-autoload but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you even requiring `vendor/autoload.php`?